# Using thunks to go from cdecl to thiscall (Linux x86)

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86, calling-convention

I've been trying to use 'thunking' so I can use member functions to legacy APIs which expects a C function. I'm trying to use a similar solution to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16785/Thunking-in-Win32-Simplifying-Callbacks-to-Non-sta). This is my thunk structure so far:

```
struct Thunk
{
    byte mov;   // ↓
    uint value; // mov esp, 'value' <-- replace the return address with 'this' (since this thunk was called with 'call', we can replace the 'pushed' return address with 'this')

    byte call;  // ↓
    int offset; // call 'offset' <-- we want to return here for ESP alignment, so we use call instead of 'jmp'

    byte sub;   // ↓
    byte esp;   // ↓
    byte num;   // sub esp, 4 <-- pop the 'this' pointer from the stack

    //perhaps I should use 'ret' here as well/instead?
} __attribute__((packed));
```

The following code is a test of mine which uses this thunk structure (but it does not yet work):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <cstdio>

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long ulong;

#include "thunk.h"

template<typename Target, typename Source>
inline Target brute_cast(const Source s)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(Source) == sizeof(Target));

    union { Target t; Source s; } u;
    u.s = s;
    return u.t;
}

void Callback(void (*cb)(int, int))
{
    std::cout << "Calling...\n";
    cb(34, 71);
    std::cout << "Called!\n";
}

struct Test
{
    int m_x = 15;

    void Hi(int x, int y)
    {
        printf("X: %d | Y: %d | M: %d\n", x, y, m_x);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Begin Execution...\n";

    Test test;

    Thunk * thunk = static_cast<Thunk*>(mmap(nullptr, sizeof(Thunk),
        PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0));

    thunk->mov = 0xBC; // mov esp
    thunk->value = reinterpret_cast<uint>(&test);

    thunk->call = 0xE8; // call
    thunk->offset = brute_cast<uint>(&Test::Hi) - reinterpret_cast<uint>(thunk);
    thunk->offset -= 10; // Adjust the relative call

    thunk->sub = 0x83; // sub
    thunk->esp = 0xEC; // esp
    thunk->num = 0x04; // 'num'

    // Call the function
    Callback(reinterpret_cast<void (*)(int, int)>(thunk));
    std::cout << "End execution\n";
}
```

If I use that code; I receive a segmentation fault within the `Test::Hi` function. The reason is obvious (once you analyze the stack in GDB) but I do not know how to fix this. The stack is not aligned properly.

The `x` argument contains garbage **but** the `y` argument contains the `this` pointer (see the `Thunk` code). That means the stack is misaligned by 8 bytes, but I still don't know why this is the case. Can anyone tell why this is happening? `x` and `y` should contain `34` and `71` respectively.

NOTE: I'm aware of the fact that this is does not work in all scenarios (such as MI and VC++ thiscall convention) but I want to see if I can get this work, since I would benefit from it a lot!

EDIT: Obviously I also know that I can use static functions, but I see this more as a challenge...

Comment: I suppose you want `mov [esp], this_param` instead of `mov esp, this_param`. But that will cause a problem because it overwrites the return address.

Comment: So, you would like to benefit from UBs?

Comment: @interjay Correct me if I'm wrong (I'm not experienced with assembly) but that still wouldn't explain why the stack is misaligned by 8 bytes (i.e why both x and y has invalid values)?

Comment: @BЈовић What do you mean by UBs? This would be useful in cases where you work with legacy C APIs which doesn't allow user data to be passed.

Comment: If it doesn't allow data to be passed, it must be with a reason. I am not that proficient in assembly to answer your question, but casting something to function pointer to UB. What works on your PC, might not work somewhere else.

Comment: @BЈовић This might not be the best example but you will see my point. Consider the `qsort` function from 'stdlib'. It takes a 'comparator' as an argument, and it cannot be a static member function, because you cannot identify which class instance it relates to (you cannot pass the 'this' pointer), you see what I mean now?

Comment: Not really. Why not [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) instead of qsort?

Comment: @BЈовић That's the whole point. This is only required when you work with **legacy** APIs (which is nearly always C APIs) where `sort` was just an example of a C function where it's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a standalone (non-member, or maybe static) `cdecl` function:

```
void Hi_cdecl(int x, int y)
{
    printf("X: %d | Y: %d | M: %d\n", x, y, m_x);
}
```

Another function calls it this way:

```
push 71
push 36
push (return-address)
call (address-of-hi)
add esp, 8 (stack cleanup)
```

You want to replace this by the following:

```
push 71
push 36
push this
push (return-address)
call (address-of-hi)
add esp, 4 (cleanup of this from stack)
add esp, 8 (stack cleanup)
```

For this, you have to read the `return-address` from the stack, push `this`, and then, push the `return-address`. And for the cleanup, add 4 (not subtract) to `esp`.

Regarding the return address - since the thunk must do some cleanup after the callee returns, it must store the original return-address somewhere, and push the return-address of the cleanup part of the thunk. So, where to store the original return-address?

- In a global variable - might be an acceptable hack (since you probably don't need your solution to be reentrant)
- On the stack - requires moving the whole block of parameters (using a machine-language equivalent of `memmove`), whose length is pretty much unknown

Please also note that the resulting stack is not 16-byte-aligned; this can lead to crashes if the function uses certain types (those that require 8-byte and 16-byte alignment - the SSE ones, for example; also **maybe** `double`).

Comment: Great answer! I'll try to see if I can fix this now. But about the 'return' issue, why can't I just use malloc? Since I use inline assembly that should be a breeze? Or would it be issues with freeing that memory...?

Comment: Using `malloc` to store a single number doesn't help: you then have to store the pointer that `malloc` returns; in normal functions you use local variables for that

Comment: @antaloyg Damn it... Well I guess I'll use member variables in that case. Anyhow I got it working now with that explanation of yours, I only need to solve the 'return' issue now. If I use a global (or member) variable, should I use the absolute address (the one returned from the '&' operand) or must it also be relative? And since I can't use 'mov' between two memory addresses directly, would it be safe to do: `mov eax, [esp]` -> `mov DWORD ['address'], eax` or is there something else I should take in consideration?

Comment: Global variable has an absolute address; member variable has address relative to `this`. As for registers - apparently there is [no problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) in using `eax` as a temporary register.